# How could I sort an array by the name of the multidimensional array not the value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this php array:

```
Array ( [5] => Theme [8] => More [6] => Plugins [7] => Settings [1] => Blog [2] => Images [3] => Pages [4] => Social Media )
```

I need to sort it by the number of the array, so this array should be:

```
Array ( [1] => Blog [2] => Images [3] => Pages [4] => Social Media [5] => Theme [6] => Plugins [7] => Settings [8] => More )
```

How can I go about sorting this array into the outcome I need in php?

Thank you.

EDIT: I need to sort the array by the name of the multidimensional array, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function:

```
ksort($a);
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(8) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Blog"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Images"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Pages"
  [4]=>
  string(12) "Social Media"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "Theme"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "Plugins"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "Settings"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "More"
}
```

[**Demonstration**](https://eval.in/398771)

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat. Reading the PHP documentation I had an issue with the wording on the sorting functions.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer when I'm allowed to. (6mins)